# Monogdb create a new field which is an array of two other fields

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to create a new column from two other columns in my collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f18a84df7b941cf3052f47"),
    "longitude" : -104.600832915448,
    "latitude" : 41.1892939609291,
    
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f18a84df7b941cf3052f48"),
    "longitude" : -108.117613649085,
    "latitude" : 39.4854579742338,
    
}
```

I essentially wanted a new column called coordinate_pair which would be an array like: [longitude, latitude]. End result of below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f18a84df7b941cf3052f47"),
    "longitude" : -104.600832915448,
    "latitude" : 41.1892939609291,
    "coordinate_pair" : [
        -104.600832915448,
        41.1892939609291
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f18a84df7b941cf3052f48"),
    "longitude" : -108.117613649085,
    "latitude" : 39.4854579742338,
    "coordinate_pair" : [
        -108.117613649085,
        39.4854579742338
    ]
}
```

I tried running the following commands:

```
db.sites.createIndex( { coordinate_pair: "2dsphere" } )
db.sites.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "coordinate_pair": [ "$longitude", "$latitude" ]
  }}
])
```

But all it does is just show me the results, it does not update the collection. Am I missing something?

Comment: `aggregate` without a `"$merge"` or `"$out"` won't update the database/collection. `aggregate` is primarily used for queries.  Perhaps you want to look at one of the varieties of [`update`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents/).

Answer (score 1):

From the mongoDB [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline),

Starting in MongoDB 4.2, the db.collection.updateMany() method can accept an aggregation pipeline that specifies the modifications to perform.

Using the aggregation pipeline allows for a more expressive update statement, such as expressing conditional updates based on current field values or updating one field using the value of another field(s).

So in your case, the solution will be:

```
db.sites.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    { $set: { coordinate_pair: [ "$longitude", "$latitude"] }}
  ]
)
```